# Python svgwrite module background color

Tags: python, svg, svgwrite

I am using the svgwrite module in my Python code and I would like to set a background color. So far I have not been able to find anything. Is there a way to do it?

I was hoping for something during the initialization:

```
import svgwrite

canvas = svgwrite.drawing.Drawing(fill="#225566") # or background="#225566", or sth similar
canvas.save('image.png')
```

Or I could probably draw rectangle all over the place, but that's just weird.

Comment: I can't help you with Python/svgwrite, but in general there is no such thing as a "fill" for the SVG as a whole.  You can set the "background-color" CSS style property on the top-most `<svg>` (but not nested SVGs) for displaying in a browser, but that probably wouldn't work with an SVG-to-PNG converter.  Nothing wrong with drawing a background coloured rectangle as your first element in the graphic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems that svg itself does not define how to set the background colour. For svgwrite I use this:

```
svg_size_width = 900
svg_size_height = 4500
dwg = svgwrite.Drawing(name, (svg_size_width, svg_size_height), debug=True)
dwg.add(dwg.rect(insert=(0, 0), size=('100%', '100%'), rx=None, ry=None, fill='rgb(50,50,50)'))
dwg.save()
```